# Change bootstrap menu according to page width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm developing a web application and I put in my application the bootstrap menu I would like when the application reaches the maximum width of max-width: 770px the menu would be the same as the menu that is in the normal width of the page.
But when giving the display none in the menu `navbar-header` it does not exit and the menu `nav navbar-nav` does not appear in the maximum width of the page of 770px

Menu in the normal width of the page

[image]

Menu at the maximum width of 770px

[image]

```
 <div class="body-wrap" >

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="azul">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" ></a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <div class="conteudo"><li><a href="#">Pagina Principal</a></li></div> 
      <div class="conteudo"> <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li></div>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <div class="conteudo"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Produtos <b class="caret"></b></a></div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Camisetas</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calças</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bermudas</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>




</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 770px) {

body{

background-color: yellow;
 }


  .navbar-header{
  display: none;
 }

  .nav .navbar-nav{

display: inline;
   }

  }
```

Comment: What do you mean normal width of the page, mobile devices are ubiquitous these days so you could call the width of an iphone screen "normal". Do you mean, you want the desktop style menu when the page is at 770px?

Comment: but as I desactivate the navbar-toggle navigation bar and display the navbar-collapse collapse navigation bar on the 770px max page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure If I got what you mean but if you want to disable navbar-collapse you can simply add this CSS:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block!important;
}

.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
  float: left !important;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
  margin-right: -15px !important;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right!important;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/t4ym3/)

Comment: but as I desactivate the navbar-toggle navigation bar and display the navbar-collapse collapse navigation bar on the 770px max page

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove:

- the button in element with class "navbar-header"
- remove css classes "collapse navbar-collapse"

In this way the button disappear and you don't need to add extra css rules.
The main bar will remain visible with all widths.

Comment: but as I desactivate the navbar-toggle navigation bar and display the navbar-collapse collapse navigation bar on the 770px max page